# incremental query vs. continuous query

Tags: sql, stream, streaming, sparql

I know that **continuous query** is a query which is registered once and it is evaluated continuously over a data stream. But, I don't understand what does **incremental query** means. I am reading about continuous data streams and the way we query for a specific pattern in the stream.

Can anyone explain me - what is an incremental query? Explanation with an example will be really helpful

Although after googling a lot, I find some definitions, but none of them explains clearly.

**UPDATE:**
I don't find the exact paper now in which I found this term, but in [this](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/527/1/2001-9.pdf) paper I can find it on page no. 6.

Comment: It would be helpful if the down voter tell openly -  how this question is not relevant or how it can be improved.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I suspect it is because your question is rather broad and unclear. You read somewhere about the notion of an 'incremental query', apparently, but you don't bother to cite a reference. Is this a term you made up yourself, or you came across it somewhere? If the latter: where? And what did that source say about what was meant?

Comment: @JeenBroekstra, Sorry. Yes, you are right. I should have attached the source document. Thanks for pointing out the reason of downvote.

Answer (score -1):

You might already have researched incremental algorithm, I think it is what you're looking for.

I have never heard of an 'incremental' query. However that sounds a lot like doctrine's schema update command [here in symfony's doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#creating-the-database-tables-schema)

Food for thought until someone come up with a better answer :)

Comment: Thanks for finding your time. But, I can't figure out  how it explains what I have asked for.

Comment: Processing continuous query requires an incremental algorithm. As far as I know continuous queries allow you to compute an expensive query as data is collected in your db. When data is inserted you want to update the result of your continuous query but you do not want to completely recompute the query, just the delta. That is where an incremental algorithm comes in. Because I have never heard of an incremental query I thought that was what you were looking for.